# Dominic is a teacher, but he also holds another job, (first order logic)

Tags: logic

I have this predicate:
Job(p,j) - Person p has a job j.
Customer(p1,p2) - Person p1 is a customer of person p2.
Boss(p1, p2) - Person p1 is the boss of person p2.

These constants:
Constants
Lecturer, Teacher, Dentist, Lawyer, Dominic, Freda

How do I say in first order logic, Dominic is a teacher, but he also holds another job.
I get so far as Job(Dominic, Teacher), however I don't know how to express, the "but" part, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"But" nearly always means the same as "and". "But" just signifies that the second conjunct is negative or unexpected. For instance, "2 is an even number but it is a prime" is no different logically to "2 is an even number and it is a prime".

In your case, "Dominic is a teacher, but he also holds another job" is equivalent to "Dominic is a teacher, and he also holds another job". Next level of detail might be "Dominic has a job as a teacher and there is another job (different from teacher) such that Dominic has that job as well".

Can you get it from there?

Comment: Job(Dominic, Teacher) ∧ Job(Dominic, X). Is that correct, also I'm having a little trouble with this now: There exists a lawyer all of whose customers are dentists. I have this ∃x Job(x, Lawyer) ∧ Customer(Dentist, x). Thanks.

Comment: No, `Job(Dominic, Teacher) ∧ Job(Dominic, X)` is not adequate because you haven't indicated what `X` is. When I wrote "there is another job", that is a hint hat you need an existential quantifier -- "there exists a job j". And when I wrote "different from teacher" it is a hint that you need to ensure that this "j" is something other than "teacher", so you need to include j<>teacher in the sentence.

Comment: ah so it would be more like?: ∃j <> Teacher Job(Dominic, j) ∧ j ¬ <> Teacher Job(Dominic, j).

Comment: Also while on the topic can I ask if this is correct? The english sentence: There exists a lawyer all of whose customers are dentists. first-order logic: ∀y ⇔ Dentist ∃x (x, Lawyer) => Customer(y , x).

Comment: Yep, that's closer. Depending on the formalism you are being taught, sometimes you can put restrictions on a quantifier, like your `∃j <> Teacher`. In other formalisms you might have to include something like `¬(j=teacher)` as a separate clause. I'd go for `Job(Dominic, Teacher) ∧ ∃j (Job(Dominic, j) ∧ ¬(j=Teacher))`.

Comment: Regarding the lawyer whose customers are dentists, it's getting to seem like too much homework assistance. Can I suggest that you rewrite the sentence with gradually increasing detail. So "There exists a lawyer all of whose customers are dentists", might be rewritten as "There exists a person who has a job as a lawyer and for all people, if they are a customer of that lawyer then they have a job as a dentist". The rewrite with the next level of detail, gradually replacing words with symbols.